# I'm having so much fun vs. I'm having fun so much

Tags: grammar, adjectives, adverbs

It's perfectly okay to say **I'm having so much fun**.

But how about **I'm having fun so much**?
Is it a grammatically correct but nonidiomatic sentence?
Or what is wrong with it?

Comment: It changes what "so much" applies to, from "fun" to "having". The first says you are having a lot of fun at the moment. The second says that you often have fun, but isn't very idiomatic.

Comment: Consider 'so much fun' to be a fixed phrase that should not be broken up and rearranged.

Comment: _So much `NP`_ should not be used alone. The full expression is _so much `NP` that `S`_, where _S_ is some result of getting so much `NP`, like _so much vodka that he died_. If you heavily stress the _so_ part, you can make it into an emphasizer like _very_; but only in speech, not in writing.